# How to select various items for each Distinct code value

Tags: sql-order-by, ssms, distinct

At the moment, I am doing this process in excel but it is taking a very long time and thought that SQL might offer a more efficient alternative.

The table, projections, is 58k rows and originally comes ordered in a nonsensical way. There are 18 columns but only two have any significance, occ_code and indcode. In excel, I am arranging in ascending by occ_code and then arranging that subset in ascending order by indcode. An example of the intended result is given below.

```
indcode     occ_code
000000       000000
110000       000000
111000       000000
000000       111011
110000       111011
120000       111011
000000       122011
```

As for SQL, could this be done with the following code.

```
Select Distinct Occ_code,indcode From dbo.projections
Order by occ_code asc, indcode asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work:

`Select Distinct Occ_code,indcode From dbo.projections Order by occ_code asc, indcode asc`

An alternative would be to use group by which would allow you to use aggregation functions:

`Select Occ_code, indcode From dbo.projections group by Occ_code, indcode Order by occ_code asc, indcode asc`

Here you could use count(*) with it to find those combined codes with no duplicates:

`Select Occ_code, indcode, count(*) From dbo.projections group by Occ_code, indcode having count(*) = 1 Order by occ_code asc, indcode asc`

Comment: Can you think of a reason that the row count of the result of the second line of code 20,523 and not 58K?

Comment: @Calflamesfann Check for duplicates using count(*) and sort by the count(*) in descending order to see, if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You must also include indcode in your select if you want it in the results.  the query as you wrote it would only give one row per distinct occ_code value.

Comment: yes - you would now get distinct pairs of those two columns, ordered by occ_code, then  indcode